# JSON response from Watson Translator Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to use Watson translator service from my node.js app through the API documentation from IBM https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemyvision/api/v1/#apiexplorer

```
var request = require("request");
var LanguageTranslatorV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/language-translator/v3');

var english_message

var languageTranslator = new LanguageTranslatorV3({
    version: '2018-05-01',
    username: '1234',
    password: '1234',
    url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api'
  });


function translatorEnglish(message) {
  var parameters = {
    text: message.text,
    model_id: 'es-en'
  };
  languageTranslator.translate(
    parameters,
    function(error, response, body) {
      if (error)
        console.log(error)
      else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    }
  );
 }
```

I get the following correct response in logs

```
{
  "translations": [
    {
      "translation": "Hi."
    }
  ],
  "word_count": 1,
  "character_count": 4
}
```

but when i try to extract the output translation value i always get the  output as `Undefined`.

```
console.log(response.translations.translation); => undefined
```

Can you please check and let me know if i am doing anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `translations` looks like an array with one item.

Comment: `response.translations[0]` gives the output `{ translation: 'Hi.' }` which is not what i needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
console.log(response.translations[0].translation); // Hi
```

This is because `translations` is an array and has one item at index `0`.

```
{
  "translations": [
    {
      "translation": "Hi."
    }
  ],
  "word_count": 1,
  "character_count": 4
}
```